# Eclipse internal error "Polling news feeds"

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11, eclipse-2018-09

I'm using Eclipse(4.9.0) on my MacBook (High Sierra, Java 11) and this error is showing sometimes, if I'm on another app, the errors create a "stack" as you see in the screenshot, it is annoying to come back to Eclipse and to close this error every time.
Can somebody help me solve this?

[image: The error showing up after a while using another app]

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

This indeed seems to be an issue when Eclipse is run with Java 11. I have created [Bug 539545](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539545) to report this.

In the meantime, you can work around this issue by disabling news feed polling. To do so, go to *Preferences... -> General -> News*, and untick the *Enable automatic news polling* option:

[image: Preferences news feed disabling]

The error window will no longer appear.

Comment: This solution is the same for Eclipse on Windows - except the Preferences menu is under the main 'Window' menu

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow The Preferences menu is under the main 'Window' menu under GNU Linux too :)

Answer (score 22):

This is caused by the http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320 - which is removal of Java EE and CORBA Modules from the standard Java 11 version.

As mentioned by @Pyves, the simple way would be unchecking "Enable automatic news polling" from the Preferences-> General -> News

But if you still need this, you can install "javax.*" bundles from the eclipse orbit repository.
Here is the latest stable repo url:
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20180905201904/repository

[image]

Comment: Just confirmed that adding the bundles does not work (JRE 11.0.1, Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) Build id: 20180917-1800). I am still getting the error message even after adding the bundles exactly as described and letting Eclipse restart.

Comment: Same issue here, doesn't resolve. AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11), Eclipse Version: Photon Release (4.8.0) Build id: 20180619-1200

Answer (score 2):

Turning off the news feed does solve this problem (Per @Pyves, unchecking "Enable automatic news polling" from Preferences-> General -> News), **but** be aware that you may get other issues because of the too-new JDK. Noga Rotman just spent several hours working out for me that Eclipse not being able to find JUnit, even though it was installed and correctly on the classpath, was because of using the new JDK (the one that is causing these same issues).

You can solve the underlying issue by uninstalling your current version of the JDK and installing an old version, then reinstalling Eclipse.
If you have the Oracle JDK you can find uninstall instructions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm#JSJIG-GUID-F575EB4A-70D3-4AB4-A20E-DBE95171AB5F) and and Java SE Development Kit 8u191 (which fixed my issues) is [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Comment: Do you have to re-install Eclipse after installing the older JDK? Or is it sufficient to update your eclipse.ini file to point it to the older JDK? I suspect it will be sufficient to update eclipse.ini (which is quite a bit easier than reinstalling it) - I'm going to give that a try, and if it works I'll comment back.

Answer (score 1):

For windows version Eclipse,

1. Enter search key string "news"
2. Check off "Enable automatic news polling"
3. Click [Apply and Close] button.

That's it.
[image]